# Create a silent audio CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

How do you create a silent audio `CMSampleBufferRef` in Swift? I am looking to append silent `CMSampleBufferRef`s to an instance of `AVAssetWriterInput`.

Comment: also remember that just starting to play a null sound may sort of pop when you start, so you might need to do a few samples of mixing, or muting whatever is playing before that sound... and also middle will only be 0 if you have a float rep, or a signed int rep, an unsigned int rep, should be filled with max/2 (ish)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't say what format you want your zeros (integer/floating point, mono/stereo, sample rate), but maybe it doesn't matter. Anyway, here's one way to create a silent CD audio style `CMSampleBuffer` in swift.

```
func createSilentAudio(startFrm: Int64, nFrames: Int, sampleRate: Float64, numChannels: UInt32) -> CMSampleBuffer? {
    let bytesPerFrame = UInt32(2 * numChannels)
    let blockSize = nFrames*Int(bytesPerFrame)

    var block: CMBlockBuffer?
    var status = CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        nil,
        blockSize,  // blockLength
        nil,        // blockAllocator
        nil,        // customBlockSource
        0,          // offsetToData
        blockSize,  // dataLength
        0,          // flags
        &block
    )
    assert(status == kCMBlockBufferNoErr)

    // we seem to get zeros from the above, but I can't find it documented. so... memset:
    status = CMBlockBufferFillDataBytes(0, block!, 0, blockSize)
    assert(status == kCMBlockBufferNoErr)

    var asbd = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
        mSampleRate: sampleRate,
        mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
        mFormatFlags: kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger,
        mBytesPerPacket: bytesPerFrame,
        mFramesPerPacket: 1,
        mBytesPerFrame: bytesPerFrame,
        mChannelsPerFrame: numChannels,
        mBitsPerChannel: 16,
        mReserved: 0
    )

    var formatDesc: CMAudioFormatDescription?
    status = CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &asbd, 0, nil, 0, nil, nil, &formatDesc)
    assert(status == noErr)

    var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?

    // born ready
    status = CMAudioSampleBufferCreateReadyWithPacketDescriptions(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        block,      // dataBuffer
        formatDesc!,
        nFrames,    // numSamples
        CMTimeMake(startFrm, Int32(sampleRate)),    // sbufPTS
        nil,        // packetDescriptions
        &sampleBuffer
    )
    assert(status == noErr)

    return sampleBuffer
}
```

Doesn't it make you sorry you asked? Do you really need silent `CMSampleBuffer`s? Can't you insert silence into an `AVAssetWriterInput` by moving the presentation time stamp forward?

Comment: Thanks this is very informative :-)  Unfortunately I do need AVAssetWriter to export a silent movie.  I'm exporting time-lapses that can't contain audio.  If I was just exporting to the camera roll it wouldn't be a problem but I'm inserting the video into an AVMutableCoposition.  AVMutableCompositionTrack seems to be bugged in iOS 9, it doesn't like inserting AVAssets without audio tracks.  This question touches on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33277354/2526115

Comment: Moving the presentation time stamp forward is also not an option because AVAssetWriter will export a video with a duration of the last time stamp.

Comment: Weird. So does the above code work for inserting silence?

Comment: I'm definitely not sorry the question was asked. So now we have such great informative example of how its done. Maybe for the purpose of silent sample, and maybe other. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you get the same result by _not_ creating an audio track at all?

Answer (score 3):

Updated for XCode 10.3. Swift 5.0.1.
Don't forget the `import CoreMedia`.

```
import Foundation
import CoreMedia

class CMSampleBufferFactory
{
    static func createSilentAudio(startFrm: Int64, nFrames: Int, sampleRate: Float64, numChannels: UInt32) -> CMSampleBuffer? {
        let bytesPerFrame = UInt32(2 * numChannels)
        let blockSize = nFrames*Int(bytesPerFrame)

        var block: CMBlockBuffer?
        var status = CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(
            allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
            memoryBlock: nil,
            blockLength: blockSize,
            blockAllocator: nil,
            customBlockSource: nil,
            offsetToData: 0,
            dataLength: blockSize,
            flags: 0,
            blockBufferOut: &block
        )
        assert(status == kCMBlockBufferNoErr)

        guard var eBlock = block else { return nil }

        // we seem to get zeros from the above, but I can't find it documented. so... memset:
        status = CMBlockBufferFillDataBytes(with: 0, blockBuffer: eBlock, offsetIntoDestination: 0, dataLength: blockSize)
        assert(status == kCMBlockBufferNoErr)


        var asbd = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
            mSampleRate: sampleRate,
            mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
            mFormatFlags: kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger,
            mBytesPerPacket: bytesPerFrame,
            mFramesPerPacket: 1,
            mBytesPerFrame: bytesPerFrame,
            mChannelsPerFrame: numChannels,
            mBitsPerChannel: 16,
            mReserved: 0
        )

        var formatDesc: CMAudioFormatDescription?
        status = CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, asbd: &asbd, layoutSize: 0, layout: nil, magicCookieSize: 0, magicCookie: nil, extensions: nil, formatDescriptionOut: &formatDesc)
        assert(status == noErr)

        var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?

        status = CMAudioSampleBufferCreateReadyWithPacketDescriptions(
            allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
            dataBuffer: eBlock,
            formatDescription: formatDesc!,
            sampleCount: nFrames,
            presentationTimeStamp: CMTimeMake(value: startFrm, timescale: Int32(sampleRate)),  
            packetDescriptions: nil,
            sampleBufferOut: &sampleBuffer
        )
        assert(status == noErr)
        return sampleBuffer
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to convert output "sampleBuffer" to URL?

Comment: I would convert CMSampleBuffer to Swift "Data" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054779/how-to-convert-cmsamplebuffer-to-data-in-swift

Comment: And then Swift "Data" to Swift "String" -> https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-convert-data-to-a-string

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a block buffer using `CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock()`.
Fill the block buffer with a bunch of zeros and then pass it into `CMAudioSampleBufferCreateWithPacketDescriptions()`.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually done this in Swift, I attempted it but found myself fighting the compiler at every turn so I switched to obj-c. The Core Media Framework is a low level C framework and was a lot easier to use without screwing around with Swifts type system. I know this isn't the answer you're looking for buy hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

[Example](https://github.com/Pescolly/BlankCMSampleBuffer/blob/master/BlankCMSampleBuffer/main.m)

Comment: An Obj-C example would be fine

Comment: @IvanLesko I put an example on github. It is a command line utility to create a single second of silence and put it into a file.