# How to convert CMSampleBuffer to Data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-media, cmsamplebuffer

I need to convert `CMSampleBuffer` to `Data` format. I am using one Third party framework for audio related task. That framework gives me the streaming (i.e Real Time audio) audio in `CMSampleBuffer` object.

Like this:

```
func didAudioStreaming(audioSample: CMSampleBuffer!) {
    //Here I need to conver this to Data format. 
    //Because I am using GRPC framework for Audio Recognization, 
}
```

Please provide me the steps to convert the `CMSampleBuffer` to `Data`.

FYI

```
    let formatDesc:CMFormatDescription? = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(audioSample)

    <CMAudioFormatDescription 0x17010d890 [0x1b453ebb8]> {
    mediaType:'soun' 
    mediaSubType:'lpcm' 
    mediaSpecific: {
        ASBD: {
            mSampleRate: 16000.000000 
            mFormatID: 'lpcm' 
            mFormatFlags: 0xc 
            mBytesPerPacket: 2 
            mFramesPerPacket: 1 
            mBytesPerFrame: 2 
            mChannelsPerFrame: 1 
            mBitsPerChannel: 16     } 
        cookie: {(null)} 
        ACL: {(null)}
        FormatList Array: {(null)} 
    } 
    extensions: {(null)}
}
```

Comment: May i ask how did you record at a sample rate of 16000?? I have called ```session.setPreferredSampleRate``` but i keep getting the sample rate in 44100

Answer (score 16):

Try below code to convert CMSampleBuffer to NSData.

```
let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)
let src_buff = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!)
let data = NSData(bytes: src_buff, length: bytesPerRow * height)
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
```

**EDIT-**

For AudioBuffer use below code -

```
var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList()
var data = Data()
var blockBuffer : CMBlockBuffer?

CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, nil, &audioBufferList, MemoryLayout<AudioBufferList>.size, nil, nil, 0, &blockBuffer)

let buffers = UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(start: &audioBufferList.mBuffers, count: Int(audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers))

for audioBuffer in buffers {
    let frame = audioBuffer.mData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    data.append(frame!, count: Int(audioBuffer.mDataByteSize))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, But I am receiving audio samples not video or image . Will it work for my case?

Comment: @Sridhar I have edited my answer, please let know whether work for you or not.

Comment: Thanks Nileash, I used your updated answer, I am getting -  Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647 "(null)"  this error coming from AudioPlayer

Comment: let formatDesc:CMFormatDescription? = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(audioSample)
<CMAudioFormatDescription 0x17010d890 [0x1b453ebb8]> {
 mediaType:'soun' 
 mediaSubType:'lpcm' 
 mediaSpecific: {
  ASBD: {
   mSampleRate: 48000.000000 
   mFormatID: 'lpcm' 
   mFormatFlags: 0xc 
   mBytesPerPacket: 4 
   mFramesPerPacket: 1 
   mBytesPerFrame: 4 
   mChannelsPerFrame: 2 
   mBitsPerChannel: 16  } 
  cookie: {(null)} 
  ACL: {(null)}
  FormatList Array: {(null)} 
 } 
 extensions: {(null)}

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)

Comment: Where you getting an error, and why are you fetch formatDesc, you should directly pass your data in your audio player like this - let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(data: data)
\n player.play()

Comment: I am getting error at playing the let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(data: data) here

Comment: Okay, Instead of initializing the audio player with the Data object directly, can you please save the file to the Documents folder, and then initialized the player with the file URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149004/discussion-between-sridhar-and-nilesh).

Comment: @Sridhar is it resolved? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm getting a warning for the let buffers = statement.  I receive "Initialization of 'UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>' results in a dangling buffer pointer"

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using `CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer` will require to call at some point `CFRelease(blockBuffer)` because the buffer is retained and if not released the pool of buffers will become eventually empty and no new `CMSampleBuffer` will be generated.

I'd suggest to get directly the data using the following:

```
CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer);
size_t lengthAtOffset;
size_t totalLength;
char *data;
CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(blockBuffer, 0, &lengthAtOffset, &totalLength, &data);

NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:totalLength];
```

Comment: This is objective-C, question was asked for Swift :) You could also add swift version

Answer (score 0):

@plamkata__'s code converted to Swift:

```
var lengthAtOffset = Int()
var totalLength = Int()
var dataPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?

if let blockBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
    CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(blockBuffer, atOffset: 0, lengthAtOffsetOut: &lengthAtOffset, totalLengthOut: &totalLength, dataPointerOut: &dataPointer)
    let audioData = Data(bytes: dataPointer!, count: totalLength)
}
```