# CMSampleBuffer to Audio Data

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, avfoundation

How do I take the ***sampleBuffer*** and translate it into Data for audio?

Here is the function that I use to get the sampleBuffer

```
func captureOutput(_ : AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    // Do something with sampleBuffer to get it into audio Data   
   // Make it come out in a data Object.
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054779/how-to-convert-cmsamplebuffer-to-data-in-swift

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.